# Cannot invoke 'URLAssetWithURL' with an argument of list type '(Anyobject!, options: nil)'

Tags: ios, swift

```
var asset = AVURLAsset.URLAssetWithURL(url, options: nil)
```

I do not understand why this error is occuring, as I am using the correct options and URL

Comment: try like this AVURLAsset(URL: url, options: nil). Make sure url is an NSURL

Comment: and how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Show how you declare your url

Comment: var url : MPMediaItem?

Comment: You should choose better names for your vars in this case it should be named mediaItem this way you don't think it is an url.

Answer (score 2):

The application is seem you url as an Anyobject, try to cast it to an NSURL or convert it from whatever it is to an url.

```
if let newUrl = url as? NSURL{
    var asset = AVURLAsset.URLAssetWithURL(newUrl, options: nil)
} else { println("Error converting url to NSURL")}
```

If the casting fail I suggest that you add the code where you are creating the url so we can see how you can change this variable to an NSURL